# microsoft boot manager replaced by grub2?

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, grub, mbr

I was running my pc with Win 8.1. I was thinking about trying linux for a long time so I decided to give it a try. I tried to install it several times but I was never able to boot to it, all I could do was boot to windows 8. On my last installation try I chose to install grub2 on that first partition sda0 (now I cant remember the name).

Now when I turn my pc on I get the grub2 screen that I never got before, but there are no SO entries! I dont really know what to do now, I am typing this from a Linux Live CD because I cant boot to any SO.

My questions are if it is possible to add like entries to both SO or if I can revert this and be able to boot my Windows 8 again.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you have a windows recovery cd/dvd? Have a friend with Windows 8 or 7? Use it to create a recovery repair disk and boot your jacked up computer with it...http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/

Comment: What exactly is "a SO entry"?

Comment: @Logman I have an bootable windows 7 pen right here I could use it to reinstall windows but If the current windows installation does not appear on grub boot list, if I installed it again probably it wont be there aswell. That will be my last move, if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is **OS**(Operating System) instead of SO.
You may not understand grub quite well. I have no idea of what Linux distro you've been trying, but generally Linux is quite firendly to Windows and it is not the other way around. 
Here are some tips:

1. Grub should not be installed on /dev/sda0 or anything like that, sdaX(where X is a digit) represents a partition of a disk. That is to say, grub should be installed on /dev/sda(if you have only one disk).
2. What you now should do is boot into LiveCD and mount **all** your Linux partitions then chroot to your installed Linux, and repair the grub. Here are the commands you may need(.

   `mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/pointX
   chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

   If you could connect to the Internet, you might would love to install os-prober(or some other names in different distro)

   `pacman -S os-prober
   grub-install /dev/sda
   grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

   Now `exit` the chroot environment and then `reboot` your PC. Boot from your harkdisk and you will got three or more items in the grub screen, select one, and enjoy the world of Linux.

Maybe you should try Ubuntu where wubi will help you out of these frustrating things.

Comment: On my first attempts I created 3 partitions, one for the OS (SO is how its said in my native language), one for swap and another for the boot. I used to install grub on this last one, but I could never boot to it so I tried a different way. I have already run the ubuntu boot-repair tool but I had no sucess repairing this mess. I have already tried to run grub-install command but it says that I this command does not exists. I will now try to do what you said, thanks for the response.

Comment: One more question, when I open gparted I get a list of all the partitions I currently have. It starts at sda1, is there that I should install grub right?

Comment: I was having an error when trying to mount this partition (sda1) - "Invalid ntfs system" - so I formated this partition but now I get the following errors running grub-install=
`root@test:/# grub-install /dev/sda1`
`grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).`
`grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/ (is /dev mounted?).`
`Could not find device for /boot: Not found or not a block device.`

Comment: Are you sure your partition mode is gpt instead of mbr? Partitioning disk with gpt on a mbr based disk will cause bunch of problems. As I said, `grub-install /dev/sda` **NOT** `grub-install /dev/sda1`, understand? Now you may run this `mount --rbind /dev /mnt/root/dev` before you chroot to newly installed Linux.

Comment: I get the exact same error with `grub-install /dev/sda`,but when I run `mount /dev/sda /mnt/point0` I get this `mount: block device /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only`
`mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/point0 busy`

Comment: well screw this, I need the computer to work and I need to get this thing working. I will be formating the whole thing and install windows 7. I usually create 3 partitions, one for the Windows, another one for backup storage, and the other to Linux. I install windows first. Btw wich partition mode should I use?

Comment: Jesus christ! Now you should stop and go to [Arch Linux Wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/) and read the beginner's guide word bye word. I started there,too. Now you have no idea of most of the concepts of Linux, keeping trying like this is a waste of time.

Comment: yeah I will, I always like to do things on my own, normally I am sucessfull, the thing is I got so confused with this new UEFI crap that makes everything so much difficult, that I messed up this hole thing, thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: If your Win8.1 is installed in with uefi enabled, then partition would be gpt, otherwise mbr mostly.